# Why is a lowercase t showing in my Sencha Touch app?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have an app that has several different pages that use Sencha Touch.  Ocassionally the app switchers between those pages via a window.location call.  When it does, on the iPhone (but not in Chrome or on Androids), I see a lowercase t in the upper right hand corner for a minute before the page rendering completes.

Has anyone seen this? Or does anyone have any idea on how to track down the cause of this?  I initially suspected that there might be an errant character on my pages, but I have checked them all carefully and don't see anything that could cause that.  I now suspect that it may be a Sencha bug, but I don't see any way to track it down since it only occurs on the iPhone.

Comment: You have a lower-case `t` sitting somewhere outside of a tag?  No real way anyone can help you find it.

Comment: I don't though.  I've carefully checked.  This is something happening in Sencha itself, because all of my views have this problem, and they all have different layout code. There's no way I *left* a t lying around somewhere in all of them.

Comment: I use SenchaTouch daily, I can assure you there is no errant `t` lying around in every app :)  Is there a common file in your project?

Comment: There are two that are common, and either one or the other is used.  They are pretty small, and I've combed them carefully. Have you ever switched between sencha "apps" with window.location?  Because the problem does NOT occur when I first load any of the pages, only when I switch between them.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the problem is in your code.  Unless you want to post code, I'm afraid there's really nothing anyone here can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be coming from jQuery (yes, I was using both jQuery and Sencha Touch) - I don't know whether jQuery was having an issue with Sencha, or whether it was just a bug, but after upgrading to jQuery 1.6.2, the problem resolved.  Also, if I removed all references to jQuery from my project, the problem resolved.